# PostGIS Create Table with Geometry

Tags: postgis, create, table

I have written a query that will create a table and perform a GROUP BY from an existing spatial table, but the table does have the geometry.  I am wondering where, and what, in this query I put to make the new table have spatial geometry (points).

Thanks...

```
SELECT st_id, name, COUNT(st_id)
    INTO climate.test_stats
FROM climate.lugdc_stations
GROUP BY st_id, name
ORDER BY count DESC;

ALTER TABLE climate.test_stats
ADD COLUMN pk_id serial PRIMARY KEY;
```

Comment: at the start of your query put CREATE TABLE <tablename> AS

Comment: Thank you, but this is what I am asking.  AS what?  I am not sure the code to use to get the geometry from an existing table.

Comment: I have added a few things to the end (based on a previous post) and it does make the geometry; however, when I try to load the geometry into QGIS it says it is an invalid layer and can not be loaded.  When I looked at the source table there are four constraints, where the new table only has one.


SELECT st_id, name, COUNT(st_id)
INTO climate.nwont_stations
FROM climate.lugdc_stations
GROUP BY st_id, name
ORDER BY count DESC;


ALTER TABLE climate.nwont_stations
ADD COLUMN pk_id serial PRIMARY KEY;


SELECT Populate_Geometry_Columns('climate.nwont_stations'::regclass);

Comment: What I am trying to do is a Group By on a specific column (st_id).  Would I be better of to use the Aggregate function ST_Accum?  If so, what would I write for my example?  I have looked at the PostGIS manual and I am not sure what to do.

Comment: I bet that in table lugdc_stations there is either a geometry or a geographic name. But anyway you have to give us the definition of all tables (test_stats, lugdc_stations), and especially also the one containing the geometries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 SELECT 
   st_id, name, 
   COUNT(st_id) AS count, 
   ST_Collect(geom) AS geom
 INTO climate.test_stats
 FROM climate.lugdc_stations
 GROUP BY st_id, name
 ORDER BY count DESC;
```

Comment: Thank you.  I tried this and got the following: 

ERROR:  column "geom" does not exist
LINE 4:   ST_Collect(geom) AS geom

Comment: I can't read the schema of your table magically, you'll have to fill the exact column names in yourself.

Comment: Thank you Paul.  This is essentially the reason for my question.  All the how-to's I have seen have been very specific and I am not sure what is need and where to find them.

Comment: @RyanGarnett Please consider accepting the answer if you problem is solved. Otherwise, please post the table schema.

Comment: In some PostGIS tables, the geometry column is called 'the_geom'. In others, it is called 'geom'. You'll have to check your table structure to figure out which.